# How to make "require"-config file only on specific file when use composer

Tags: php, composer-php

How require config file on only on another file when use composer?

Consider have a file called "config.php" in root in this file we have some variable like $site_url :

```
$config = [
    // e.g (http://example.com or https://exmaple.com)
    "site_url" => "http://localhost"
];
```

and have a class called "DBConnect" in include folder "include/DBConnect.php" now we want use variable saved on config.php in class "DBConnect" , well write require "../config.php"; and use variable.

```
<?php


namespace Admin\includes;
require "../config.php";

class DBConnect
{
    //dsn : engine:Servername;DbName;charset;
    protected $engine;
    protected $servername;
    protected $dbname;
    protected $charset;



    public function __construct()
    {


    }
}
```

```
index.php
<?php
require  "vendor/autoload.php";

$tp1 = new \Admin\includes\DBConnect();
```

now we call getname class in index.php , when called it php return error

```
Warning: require(../config.php): failed to open stream....
```

Answer (score 1):

Make path relative to current directory by using [`__DIR__`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) magic constant:

```
require __DIR__ . "/../config.php";
```

Comment: thanks for your help
issue solved. but now without global keyword can't access config.php variable in class ,why? because use namespace or is there something else?

Comment: Using global variables is a bad practice. Making config.php part of a library is a bad practice too. It would be the best to require config in index.php or controller code and pass $config as a parameter to `new \Admin\includes\DbConnect($config);`